# Can you store functions with parameters in a list and call them later in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

For example, when I have:

```
def function(text):
  print(text)

mylist = [function('yes'),function('no')]

mylist[0]
```

It just prints yes and no and doesn't do anything with `mylist[0]`.

I want it to be able to call the function with parameters in the list and not have the functions run when the program starts. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes in Python functions are [first-class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) objects so you can stored them in a list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store functions in list and call them later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472704/store-functions-in-list-and-call-them-later)

Comment: Almost. I'm really trying to store the parameters as well without making multiple functions and calling it on the spot. Thanks though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like you want to store the functions pre-bound with parameters. You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to give you a function with some or all of the parameters already defined:

```
from functools import partial

def f(text):
    print(text)

mylist = [partial(f, 'yes'), partial(f,'no')]

mylist[0]()
# yes

mylist[1]()
# no
```

Comment: You could also use `lambda` for this:  `mylist = [lambda: f('yes'), lambda: f('no')]`

Answer (score 1):

You can store functions as parameters, since functions in python are treated as first class citizens, which means you can effectively use them / treat them as you would a variable.

In your case, it isn't working because you're calling the function, not referencing the function.

```
mylist = [functionA,functionB]

mylist[0]('yes')
```

Here I've stored the references of the funcitons into a list, instead of calling them.

When you use (), you're effectively calling the function on the spot.

Comment: Is there another way to store the parameters without making multiple functions? I'm on the verge using strings and eval(). I'm trying to get something more like this:

`mylist = [functionA('hi'),functionA('bye'),functionB('hi'),functionB('bye')]
mylist[0]`

Answer (score 0):

If you print `mylist` you will see that it contains `None`, which is the default return value of functions that don't have a `return` statement. You are, in fact, simply calling your function and saving the return value in a list.