# How do I put functions in a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I would like to use a switch statement in Python, but since there is not a switch statement in python, I would like to use a list of functions. However, when I define the list, the functions are executed.

Here is my code:

```
shapes = [drawSquare(), drawRectangle(), myTurtle.circle(10), drawTriangle(), drawStar()]
```

Here is the output using turtle:

[image: output]

How do I define the list of functions without python running the functions?

Comment: remove the brackets `()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store functions in list and call them later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472704/store-functions-in-list-and-call-them-later) and [Python argument binders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277922/python-argument-binders)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the brackets `()`

**Ex:**

```
shapes = [drawSquare, drawRectangle, myTurtle.circle, drawTriangle, drawStar]
```

**Demo:**

```
def add(a,b):
    return a + b

def sub(a,b):
    return a - b

lst = [add, sub]
for i in lst:
    print(i(3,2))
```

Comment: This might be improved by further explanation of _why_ this solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

By adding the `()` after the function name you are calling the function. To have a list of the callable functions simply change your example to read:

`shapes = [drawSquare, drawRectangle, myTurtle.circle, drawTriangle, drawStar]`

and to call one of the shapes do `shapes[pos](args)` e.g. to draw the circle per your example: `shapes[2](10)` (for those who aren't aware list positions begin at 0).

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the reference to the function (`drawSquare`) in the list, not the function (`drawSquare()`) because you don't want your function called exactly at the moment when it is declared.

`shapes = [drawSquare, drawRectangle, myTurtle.circle, drawTriangle, drawStar]`

You can later call the functions  using

`[i(10) for i in shapes]`

Or you can use a for loop if you want to give different arguments to each function.

Comment: Using `f`  in your list comprehension rather than `i` as they're functions seems like a better idea. Also, list comprehensions are awesome, _but_ if you don't actually need a list of the results, a regular old for loop is a better idea.